# AppleScript - cycle through desktops

Tags: macos, applescript

I am writing a script that will cycle through desktops on macOS

I try to move between desktops using shortcuts "ctrl+right" and "ctrl+left", which I set up on my machine to move to a right and a left desktop respectively.

```
# move 4 desktops to the right and back
tell application "System Events"
    repeat 4 times
        key code 124 using (control down)
        key code 123 using (control down)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Once I get to a desktop with a fullscreen RDP session, the RDP session starts receiving the ctrl+-> instead of the macOS.

How can I move focus from the RDP session back to macOS (or cycle through desktops in a different way)?

Comment: Which RDP app are you using? My guess is that once the RDP app receives focus, it starts intercepting key strokes. Some RDP apps have a way to lock that down, so, say, you'd have to press a certain key to activate it for keystroke acceptance. If the RDP app has that capability, you'd probably want to turn it on to prevent it from "eating" the script key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this AppleScript which switches to desktop 2 :

```
tell application "Mission Control" to launch
tell application "System Events"
    delay .1
    -- button 2 means desktop 2
    click button 2 of list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
    key code 53 --  # Esc key on US English Keyboard
end tell
```

I have not found what's the logic of those groups and I'm not sure how/if you can adapt it to suit your requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you adapted my solution to your requirements ? It could be extremely useful for other people.

Comment: I haven't yet - this solution works but only once. When I try to do it twice or more, I  get "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of process \"Dock\". Invalid index." number -1719 from group 1 of process "Dock". I didn't pursue it enough to formulate a meaningful follow up question :)